# Infinite series - (n,x)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let's consider $$f(a,b)=ab+a=a(b+1)$$
$$S=\{a,b,f(a;b),f(b+f(a;b)),f(f(a;b)+f(b+f(a;b)),...\}$$
Let's start with some concrete examples:
$$1, 3, 4, 15, 64, 975, ...$$
$$2, 3, 8, 27, 224, 6075$$
$$3, 5, 18, 95, 1728$$
$$4, 6, 28, 174, 4900$$
We can see that the 5th number is a perfect square only if $a^{2}b+a$ is a perfect square.But that's not the thing I'm interested in
$${1\over a} + {1\over b}+{1\over a(b+1)}+...$$
So let's try some values
$${1\over 2}+{1\over 3}+{1\over 8}+{1\over 27}+{1\over 224}+{1\over 6075}+... $$which approaches $1$.The convergence is very fast and convenient.So we got an integer, let's try some more numbers.
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{14}+\frac{1}{90}+\frac{1}{1274}+... \rightarrow 1.25$$
After trying many examples I figured out the general formula for $n,x$ is $$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{n+1}{nx}$$ But we started with $1\over n$ so we get $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{n(x+1)}+\frac{1}{x+(n(x+1)+1)}+...=\frac{n+1}{nx}$$ From what I tested the formula holds for any real $(n,x)$ different from $0$  except for the pairs $(n,-1),(-1,1)$.
I really doubt this is anything new but how do you demonstrate this?I am also interested in the series $$\frac{1}{n}+ \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{nx}+\frac{1}{nx^2}+\frac{1}{n^2x^3}-\frac{1}{n^3x^5}+...$$

Comment: Try using MathJax- http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference As it stands. it is difficult to read your post.

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake You can use `[title here](link here)` to make links look more professional.  =D

Comment: @SimpleArt Haha Will try to adjust my future posts to this elegant form!

Comment: I don't get the pattern in the last series.

Comment: 2 positive, 1 negative.The next one is the product of the previous two.